# Font doesn't load in production with heroku / ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, fonts

my custom font is loaded in development but not on heroku, could you help me figure it out please ?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Syne";
  src: asset-url('/assets/Syne-Regular.otf') format("truetype");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Syne-Title";
  src: asset-url('/assets/Syne-Extra.otf') format("truetype");
}


$body-font: "Syne";
$headers-font: "Syne-Title";
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make `fonts` folder under `assets` folder and move fonts files to that folder. And add `fonts` folder to assets path.

```rb
config.assets.path << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
```

And just define fonts using `font-url.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Syne";
  src: font-url('Syne-Regular.otf') format("truetype");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Syne-Title";
  src: font-url('Syne-Extra.otf') format("truetype");
}


$body-font: "Syne";
$headers-font: "Syne-Title";
```